# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ccbmlib'

Tags: python

when I'm trying to run this in Jupyternotebook

```
from setuptools import setup

import re 
version =""
with open ("ccbmlib") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ *= *['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]",line)
        if version_match:
            version = version_match.group(1)'''
```

Comment: Have you check you've got the right permissions to read that file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

please check wheather if your 'ccbmlib' file is open. If it is open, close the file and try it again

Comment: even then also I'm getting the same error